# onBindViewHolder вызывается, даже если areContentsTheSame возвращает true

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

В статье про [`DiffUtil`](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/504-primer-ispolzovanija-android-diffutil.html) сказано, что биндинг (метод `onBindViewHolder`) должен вызываться только для тех item-ов адаптера, для которых произошло обновление данных, а если данные не изменились - вызываться не должен. И я реализовала свой класс, который наследуется от `DiffUtil.Callback()`, и его метод `areContentsTheSame` отрабатывает правильно - возвращает true, если item не изменился, и false - если изменился. Но метод `onBindViewHolder` вызывается всегда, вне зависимости от того, что возвращает `areContentsTheSame`. В чём может быть причина этого?

Comment: Если у вас список будет лежать в ScrollView или ему подобных.

Comment: @Valeriy, да нет, у меня RecyclerView лежит в LinearLayout (а тот в ещё одном LinearLayout в другом layout-e).

Comment: Может не убрали вызов `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Покажите как обновляете адаптер.

Comment: @woesss, вы правы, спасибо! Если опубликуете как ответ, обязательно приму)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общая схема использовании `DiffUtil` выглядит так:

```
 // берём старые данные
 List oldList = mAdapter.getData();
 // сравниваем с новыми и получаем результат сравнения
 DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new MyCallback(oldList, newList));
 // меняем данные в адаптере на новые
 mAdapter.setData(newList);
 // уведомляем адаптер об изменениях
 result.dispatchUpdatesTo(mAdapter);
```

Соответственно обычные уведомления `adapter.notify...` вызывать не следует, вместо этого используется метод [`DiffUtil.DiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(Adapter)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.DiffResult.html#dispatchUpdatesTo(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)), который уведомляет адаптер наиболее оптимальным способом.